# MSAL for Android: SHA-256 digest error (AuthenticationCallback.class) during Instant Run with androidx

Tags: android, azure-ad-msal, androidx, android-instant-run

Is there a way to get MSAL working together with Instant Run and AndroidX?

Microsoft Authentication Library 0.2.1 works fine out-of-the-box with Android Studio but gives build errors after migrating to androidx when Instant Run is enabled.

The following error is reported by Java compiler during build:

> java.lang.SecurityException: SHA-256 digest error for com/microsoft/identity/client/AuthenticationCallback.class

Repro:

1. Create a new Android Studio project
2. Ensure Instant Run is enabled (File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run)
3. Follow instructions here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android
4. Debug. Things should work out fine.
5. Add the following to gradle.properties:

   - android.useAndroidX=true
   - android.enableJetifier=true
6. Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX (unrelated: if needed fix layouts etc)
7. Try to start debugging
8. Now compiler reports the errors mentioned above
9. Disable Instant Run
10. Debug
11. Now things work out fine.

My MainActivity looks as follows:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

val CLIENT_ID = "<My Client Id>"
val SCOPES = arrayOf("https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read")
private lateinit var sampleApp: PublicClientApplication

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    sampleApp = PublicClientApplication(
        this.applicationContext,
        CLIENT_ID
    )
    sampleApp.acquireToken(this, SCOPES, getAuthInteractiveCallback());
}

private fun getAuthInteractiveCallback(): AuthenticationCallback {
    return object : AuthenticationCallback {
        override fun onSuccess(authenticationResult: AuthenticationResult) {
            val accessToken = authenticationResult.getAccessToken()
        }
        override fun onError(exception: MsalException) {
            if (exception is MsalClientException) {
                /* Exception inside MSAL, more info inside MsalError.java */
            } else if (exception is MsalServiceException) {
                /* Exception when communicating with the STS, likely config issue */
            }
        }
        override fun onCancel() {
            /* User canceled the authentication */
        }
    }
}

/* Handles the redirect from the System Browser */
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    sampleApp.handleInteractiveRequestRedirect(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
}
```

Edit: GitHub issue https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/354

Comment: As stated on Github this is a known issue but the product team has not triaged it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work now (don't know when it was fixed or how but both MSAL 0.2.2 and 0.3.1-alpha seem to work with April 10, 2019 build of Android Studio).

Answer (score 2):

I am integrating AD login in my Android App, and when I enabled Instant Run I started to get this issue. So I **Disabled Instant Run** again and everything is working fine now.